# Which method should I use to create my first open source Ruby Gem with Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Should I use the new Rails 3.1 `rails plugin new` command, jeweler or bundler to create my first Ruby on Rails Gem? Which tutorials would you recommend to help me get started with writing open source Gems for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails plugin new` creates an empty gem, that immediately hooks into rails. So it does creates a "frame" for you to fill in.

You will then still need either `bundler` or `jeweler` to actually convert this set of files to a gem and publish it.

Which you would choose from the two is a bit a matter of taste. Lately I find a lot of people are actually advocating to use `bundler`. But with `bundler` it still is mainly a manual process.

I personally believe it still is very interesting to use `jeweler`. What are the advantages of using jeweler:

- use a `Gemfile` as in any rails or other project, jeweler will generate a gemspec that corresponds to that. Note that this is opposite to what Yehuda from bundler fame proposes: he proposes to fill in the gemspec manually, and then lets the `Gemfile` use that by specifying `gemspec` in the file.
- adds a set of rake tasks to make your life easier to publish and build your gem
- allows easy version management
- very well integrated with git, will automatically tag, push, commit.

In short I still recommend to use `jeweler`, after doing a `rails plugin new`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Ruby gems are pretty simple, and Rails plugins are just gems that in some way touch Rails APIs. (as the other answer pointed out, `Railtie`s are a good way to hook into Rails). To write a gem, designate a folder, and have in it:

- `<gemname>.gemspec`: this lists the gem's name, version, authors, website, a list of gem dependencies and a list of files to include in the gem. (Rails' `plugin new` and Bundler gem will both generate good .gemspecs for you, see below)
- `lib/<gemname>.rb`: this is the main code of your gem. Usually this contains a class or a module named after your gem. (Rails' `plugin new` goes with module).

Everything else is optional, but good practices include:

- `test/` or `spec/`: this is where your tests go. Because a Rails plugin is usually used in an app, Rails' `plugin new` makes a dummy app in `test/`. If your gem is pretty standalone, with no explicit Rails integration, you don't need the dummy app.
- README, for describing what you gem does and how it's to be used.

You can make this folder and, critically, the `.gemspec` file entirely by hand, but the two tools will give you the following:

Bundler does for you:

- creates a `Gemfile` for you and automatically includes dependencies specified in your `<gemname>.gemspec` in the bundle (it's a single `Gemfile` command, `gemspec`)
- creates a sample `<gemname>.gemspec` for you, sets it up to pull your gem's version from `lib/<gemname>/version.rb`
- sets up using Git to generate a list of gem files (convenient, but the gem-building machine needs to have Git installed). Usually I do this using Rake, but it's more annoying.

Rails' `plugin new` does the `Gemfile` and `.gemspec`, just like Bundler. Also:

- Rails uses Ruby to generate the list of gemfiles. Nice.
- It sets up a minimal directory structure, mostly empty, for you.
- It sets up a sample test, and an entire dummy app(!) for the test to run against. I just saw this, and it strikes me as genius.

Rails will also make you a `Rakefile`, for adding rake tasks, and both tools will preconfigure a .gitignore for Git to ignore some common products.

To test your gem in an actual app, do `gem build <gemname>.gemspec`, and add `gem <gemname>` to your app's `Gemfile`. This will make a -.gem file, which contains the whole gem. You can `gem install <gemname>-<version>.gem`, and Bundler will pick it up.

When you're ready to publish, `gem push <gemname>-<version>.gem` will push it up to RubyGems.org. See http://rubygems.org for details on getting an account and pushing gems.

Also, while you're developing, you'll want to make changes to your gem and not have to keep building (and installing) versions. Unit testing will take care of some of that, but if you'd like to use your gem directly from source, Bundler has a fantastic tool:

`gem <gemname>, :path => "<path/to/your/gems/folder>"`

The folder is the one that contains the `.gemspec` file.

Does anyone know any reason to use jeweler? I'd love know what it does more than these guys. Generally, writing `gemspec`s by hand is pretty easy for me, once you've got one template to copy-and-paste-and-modify. Also, if I made any mistakes or omissions in what each tool gives you, I've made the answer a wiki so they can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Since gems are easier to install and manage, it might be best to use `jeweler` to create your gem. The best way to find inspiration is to open up the source of any gem that has Rails integration and see how they do it. Generally this is done through the Railties facility.